# (ASP NET MVC4 ou 5) Como passar um nome personalizado pelo XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Pessoal a pergunta é a seguinte, eu tenho um `<input type="file" id="fileupload"/>` e um campo `<input type="text id="Nome"/>`. Para passar ele pro meu controller, eu faço o seguinte:

```
var data = $("#fileupload").get(0).files[0];
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("Files", data);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/Home/UploadFiles", true);
xhr.send(formdata);
```

até ai tudo bem, o problema é que eu queria, junto com o arquivo, passar o nome inputado pelo usuário no elemento "Nome".
Lá do outro lado eu iria salvá-lo com o novo nome (mantendo a extensão) em algum lugar qualquer.
Tentei de tudo e não consegui passar o nome... 
Como eu posso fazer?

Desde já obrigado!

Obs: Cigano Morrison, meu controller é esse:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult UploadFiles()
{
    //Pego o arquivo
    HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[0] as HttpPostedFileBase;

    //Pego a extensao dele para selecionar o tipo
    string extensao = hpf.FileName.Substring(hpf.FileName.Length - 4).ToLower();

    //Seleciono o tipo de arquivo e retorno se não for o que eu quero
    if (!(extensao == ".jpg" || extensao == ".gif" || extensao == ".png" || extensao == ".pdf"))
    {
        return Content("{\"success\":\"" + false + "\",\"message\":\"" + "Estensão não permitida!" + "" + "\"}", "application/json");
    }

    //Configuro o nome do arquivo para salvá-lo (nessa parte eu realmente queria o nome passado pelo usuário)
    string fileName = hpf.FileName.Replace(" ","").Replace(".","").Replace("'","").ToUpper() + "-" + String.Format("{0:yyyyMMddhhmmss}", DateTime.Now) + extensao;

    //Salvo o arquivo
    string savedFileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Empresa"), fileName);
    hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName);
    return Content("{\"success\":\"" + true + "\",\"message\":\"" + "Upload finalizado com sucesso!" + "" + "\"}", "application/json");

}
```

Comment: Você pode colocar o método do seu Controller que recebe essa requisição?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acrescente ao `FormData`:

```js
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("Files", data);
formdata.append("Nome", $("#Nome").val());
```

E ao `Controller`:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult UploadFiles(String Nome)
{ ... }
```

Estou supondo que tem pelo menos [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) no projeto.

Comment: Funcionou!!! Muito obrigado !